# Vim plugin uninstall failed aftermath :(

Tags: vim, pathogen

I was installing some packages via pathogen and did not like one of the color themes and deleted those packages via terminal.
Ever since then when I execute vim thankYou.js ( :) ), I get this.

[Failed. HELP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFXyX.png)

How do I remove those '--- options --' and confirmations? I just want to go straight to vim.

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should try following the explanation at on [Vim-FAQ  2.5](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5):

> 2.5. I have a "xyz" (some) problem with Vim. How do I determine it is a
>        problem with my setup or with Vim?  / Have I found a bug in Vim?
>
> (...)
>
> ```
> vim -u ~/.vimrc --noplugin -N -i NONE
> ```
>
> This will simply use your .vimrc as configuration file, but not load
>   any plugins. If the error occurs this time, the error is possibly
>   caused by some configuration option inside your .vimrc file. Depending
>   on the length of your vimrc file, it can be quite hard to trace the
>   origin within that file.
>
> The best way is to add :finish command in the middle of your .vimrc.
>   Then restart again using the same command line. If the error still
>   occurs, the bug must be caused because of a setting in the first half
>   of your .vimrc. If it doesn't happen, the problematic setting must be
>   in the second half of your .vimrc. So move the :finish command to the
>   middle of that half, of which you know that triggers the error and
>   move your way along, until you find the problematic option. If your
>   .vimrc is 350 lines long, you need at a maximum 9 tries to find the
>   offending line (in practise, this can often be further reduced, since
>   often lines depend on each other).
>
> If the problem does not occur, when only loading your .vimrc file, the
>   error must be caused by a plugin or another runtime file (indent
>   autoload or syntax script). Check the output of the :scriptnames
>   command to see what files have been loaded and for each one try to
>   disable each one by one and see which one triggers the bug. Often
>   files that are loaded by vim, have a simple configuration variable to
>   disable them, but you need to check inside each file separately.

Comment: Thank you for the tip :D